# How to jump between bookmarks in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm analysing a package that's quite big and as I'm going down, I've selected a few lines that I deem important, every time I click on the line number, PL/SQL Developer marks the line with a blue number starting from zero as the image show. I know there's a hotkey to jump between them so that I don't have to drag the wheelbar and find them on my own. Does anyone know how to do that?

Example

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can quickly move between PL/SQL Developer bookmarks by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and then the number of the bookmark.

If you want to change that keyboard mapping, go to Configure-->Preferences and modify the "Editor: Goto Bookmark" value.